# JQUERY. Как вызвать событие change?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#selector> option").each(function() 
    {
        $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
    });

    $("#selector").trigger("change");
});

$("#selector").on('change',
    function () {
     alert("ПРИВЕТ!");
});
```

Я как то неправильно использую `trigger`? При ручном накликивании `<option>` - событие срабатывает ведь.

```
<select class="form_select"  id="selector" multiple="multiple">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Если приведенный код запустить здесь в сниппете - всё работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На события надо подписываться перед их запуском.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#selector").on('change',
        function () {
            alert("ПРИВЕТ!");
        });

    $("#selector> option").each(function () {
        $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
    });

    $("#selector").trigger("change");
});
```